# Multiple volume device on Ubuntu Multipass

Tags: multipass

I am using Ubuntu Multipass and would like to launch an instance with an additional volume device e.g. /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc since sad already exist with a partition.
I would also like to know how to create an additional device on the instance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet tried, but apparently it can be done using multipass with the libvirt driver.
The procedure is documented here: https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/135#issuecomment-391141480